# htaccess rewrite pretty url without changing rewritebase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Attempting to rewrite a few different URLs without changing the RewriteBase. The following URLs with queries:

```
http://example.com/directory1/directory2/job?id=100
http://example.com/directory3/directory4/profile?id=200
```

would become:

```
http://example.com/directory1/directory2/job/100
http://example.com/directory3/directory4/profile/200
```

Currently rules:

```
RewriteRule ^directory1/directory2/job/([0-9]+)$ ./directory1/directory2/job?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^directory3/directory4/profile/([0-9]+)$ ./directory3/directory4/profile?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^directory1/directory2/job/([0-9]+)$ ./directory1/directory2/job?id=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^directory3/directory4/profile/([0-9]+)$ ./directory3/directory4/profile?id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: So what is not working with the rules in question?

Comment: No errors. Editing Question with full htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules in this order:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/directory1/directory2/job)\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/directory3/directory4/profile)\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteRule ^(directory1/directory2/job)/([0-9]+)$ $1?id=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(directory3/directory4/profile)/([0-9]+)$ $1?id=$2 [L,QSA]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I'm still getting nothing and no errors. Adding in other conditions and rules are working just fine. Do I need to define a query string?

Comment: $_GET is not accessible, I thought it was the order again, but that didn't help

Comment: Is `directory1/directory2/job` actually a `directory1/directory2/job.php` file? Also are you using some framework like WP/Joomla etc?

Comment: Using Laravel, so it's a route/blade

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but I suspect front controller of Larael doesn't like internal rewrite rules to modify `$_GET` as the case with WP/Joomla etc.